# Drag elements around with gravity effect

Tags: javascript, gravity

I want to accomplish something similar to what photoshop.com has and this site here: http://mrdoob.com/projects/chromeexperiments/google_gravity/

Does anyone know how to do this with javascript (preferably jquery) ?

Comment: this is soo cool... a physics engine in javascript :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jPhysics demo can be found online at http://www.inf.ufrgs.br/~rcpinto/physics/ and downloaded from http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jphysics or from Google at http://code.google.com/p/jqueryphysics/

Answer (score 1):

I think the google example used [Box2Djs](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/index2.html).   I have used box2d for python and its great.