# Matter.js Gravity Point

Tags: matter.js

Is it possible to create a single gravity / force point in matter.js that is at the center of x/y coordinates?

I have managed to do it with d3.js but wanted to enquire about matter.js as it has the ability to use multiple polyshapes.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021841

Comment: Link is dead, probably due to Heroku free tier disappearing recently. Do we have an update to that for posterity?

Answer (score 4):

The illustrious answer [has arisen](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/pull/132):

> not sure if there is any interest in this. I'm a fan of what you have created. In my latest project, I used matter-js but I needed elements to gravitate to a specific point, rather than into a general direction. That was very easily accomplished. I was wondering if you are interested in that feature as well, it would not break anything.
>
> All one has to do is setting engine.world.gravity.isPoint = true and then the gravity vector is used as point, rather than a direction. One might set:
>
> ```
> engine.world.gravity.x = 355;
> engine.world.gravity.y = 125;
> engine.world.gravity.isPoint = true;
> ```
>
> and all objects will gravitate to that point.
>
> If this is not within the scope of this engine, I understand. Either way, thanks for the great work.

Comment: could you please make a little demo of this functionality?
I was trying around for now about two hours and couldn't get it work.

Comment: >= 0.17.0, use `engine.gravity`. World is deprecated.

Comment: @ggorlen would love to see an example as I see no reference of `isPoint` in the docs.

Comment: @ZachSaucier The merge request that was linked by this answer which implements `isPoint` was closed unmerged, with the final comment by the author of the MJS library pointing to a plugin, https://github.com/liabru/matter-attractors.

Comment: I added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74816915/6243352) that hopefully clarifies the situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the [matter-attractors](https://github.com/liabru/matter-attractors) plugin. Here's their [basic example](https://github.com/liabru/matter-attractors/blob/3fc7aa5fecde1d1351f7662b21f3977e586fbeb3/docs/examples/basic.js):

```js
Matter.use(
  'matter-attractors' // PLUGIN_NAME
);

var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Events = Matter.Events,
    Runner = Matter.Runner,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    World = Matter.World,
    Body = Matter.Body,
    Mouse = Matter.Mouse,
    Common = Matter.Common,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

// create engine
var engine = Engine.create();

// create renderer
var render = Render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine: engine,
  options: {
    width: Math.min(document.documentElement.clientWidth, 1024),
    height: Math.min(document.documentElement.clientHeight, 1024),
    wireframes: false
  }
});

// create runner
var runner = Runner.create();

Runner.run(runner, engine);
Render.run(render);

// create demo scene
var world = engine.world;
world.gravity.scale = 0;

// create a body with an attractor
var attractiveBody = Bodies.circle(
  render.options.width / 2,
  render.options.height / 2,
  50, 
  {
  isStatic: true,

  // example of an attractor function that 
  // returns a force vector that applies to bodyB
  plugin: {
    attractors: [
      function(bodyA, bodyB) {
        return {
          x: (bodyA.position.x - bodyB.position.x) * 1e-6,
          y: (bodyA.position.y - bodyB.position.y) * 1e-6,
        };
      }
    ]
  }
});

World.add(world, attractiveBody);

// add some bodies that to be attracted
for (var i = 0; i < 150; i += 1) {
  var body = Bodies.polygon(
    Common.random(0, render.options.width), 
    Common.random(0, render.options.height),
    Common.random(1, 5),
    Common.random() > 0.9 ? Common.random(15, 25) : Common.random(5, 10)
  );

  World.add(world, body);
}

// add mouse control
var mouse = Mouse.create(render.canvas);

Events.on(engine, 'afterUpdate', function() {
    if (!mouse.position.x) {
      return;
    }

    // smoothly move the attractor body towards the mouse
    Body.translate(attractiveBody, {
        x: (mouse.position.x - attractiveBody.position.x) * 0.25,
        y: (mouse.position.y - attractiveBody.position.y) * 0.25
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.12.0/matter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/matter-attractors@0.1.6/build/matter-attractors.min.js"></script>
```

Historical note: the "gravity point" functionality was proposed as a feature in MJS as [PR #132](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/pull/132) but it was closed, with the author of MJS (liabru) offering the matter-attractors plugin as an alternate. At the time of writing, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31938153/6243352) misleadingly seems to indicate that functionality from the PR was in fact merged.

Unfortunately, the attractors library is 6 years outdated at the time of writing and raises a warning when using a newer version of MJS than 0.12.0. From discussion in [issue #11](https://github.com/liabru/matter-attractors/issues/11), it sounds like it's OK to ignore the warning and use this plugin with, for example, 0.18.0. Here's the warning:

> matter-js: Plugin.use: matter-attractors@0.1.4 is for matter-js@^0.12.0 but installed on matter-js@0.18.0.

Behavior seemed fine on cursory glance, but I'll keep 0.12.0 in the above example to silence it anyway. If you do update to a recent version, note that [`Matter.World` is deprecated](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/World.html) and should be replaced with `Matter.Composite` and `engine.gravity`.