# Creating gravity point with Matter.js

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a point of gravity in the center of a web page for [Matter.js](https://brm.io/matter-js/) objects to be pulled towards, functioning like a blackhole. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: See [Matter.js Gravity Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938109/matter-js-gravity-point?rq=1)