# Attract bodies to each other MatterJS

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I am using MATTER JS.

I would like to know if it is possible to attract the bodies in the world to each other? Say i had 15 balls bouncing around the canvas, to have them have some sort of attraction to each other leading to them clumping together.

Comment: Sure, it's possible. There's even a [plugin](https://github.com/liabru/matter-attractors) for this. Please [edit] the post to share what you've tried and provide details of your use case so the question is on topic. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

I have only tied looking at the documentation of Matter Js. I was not able to find anything that attracted bodies to each other.

I have now installed this plugin with NPM and tried to follow the instructions. 

1. Npm install matter-attractors
2. Matter.use('matter-attractors'); in my TS file

I keep getting the same 'dependency no resolving' error. I do not know how to load the plugin properly it seems. Any tips? Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] the post to provide a [mcve] of your code and package.json.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matter.js Gravity Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938109/matter-js-gravity-point)